Is "???" a valid version of ellipsis?
I'm marking essays for the IB (International Baccalaureate), and I've run into two student essays from students in the UK (don't know if that makes a difference) where they've identified the use of "???" in newspaper articles as a form of ellipsis.
After seeing it twice in two random student essays, I'm wondering if this is an accurate assessment.
Here's The Guardian article where one instance was identified.

The student identified the "???" as representing a vacated space where a statistic would have gone.
In this sense, it seems reasonable to call this ellipsis. It does represent an omission, and it also mimics three periods. It would also seem reasonable to call something like "---" an ellipsis as well.
Does this qualify as ellipsis?

It's probably better to regard ??? as a placeholder, as something where a statistic should go, rather than marking where something has been omitted or removed. Similar things include abbreviations like TBA/TBC/TBD (to be announced, confirmed, decided, etc), TODO, XXX used to mark temporary code, blank spaces, boxes with a line or cross through used in typesetting to indicate the space for a picture, etc. Asking whether it qualifies as an ellipsis is meaningless because sources differ on what exactly is an ellipsis (e.g. triple-comma ,,,) and will depend on context, which you do not provide.

But for avoidance of doubt, "???" can't be used in many places you use "..." - e.g. in quotations formatted according to academic style guides, or to indicate a voice trailing off. In punctuation "???" is more likely to indicate a stunned/shocked questioning, particularly in informal contexts.

@StuartF, for context, are you referring to The Guardian's style guide?

Are you asking about the syntactic role that "???" plays in a sentence, or about the meaning and classification of "???" as punctuation?

@alphabet There's some overlap. I'm referring to a student essay, so I think the student has conflated the two concepts of ellipsis. I'm more interested in the syntactic role that ??? plays in this sub heading as a stand-in for data.

One example is not sufficient grounds to claim acceptability.

No, and in the Posted example it's not trying to be an ellipsis, nor anything of the kind.
Here, '???' is a wannabe stand-in for mathematical 'X', used because - perhaps not unreasonably - The Guardian thought readers might not understand 'X', or cared more about how visually, 'X' would clash with real numbers such as '124'
Sadly, the Guardian failed to notice that the generic equivalent to '6,500' would really be '?,???'
Broadly, that's the Guardian for you!
